# Save json table data to SQL Server database using stored procedure (c# backend)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, json, ajax

I have a html table and i need to save the entire table in backend database using C#.

Can someone please share an example of how to achieve this ?

The html table is converted to json using stringify and ajax post method posts the table data to server side. However, since I am new to this, I do not have idea of how to proceed for this.

I tried searching online and found that we need to create a store procedure which will let us save the table to database. Any help is appreciated

PS- if I do a post of the entire table, only initial 10-15 rows gets passed to C# side. The others don't get passed. What could be the reason of the entire table data not getting passed? I read about max limit for ajax post and tried to change settings in `web.config` to allow maximum data but it didn't work.

Comment: Post example of the code that you currently have including the database table format

Comment: @Eminem- i am trying to get a hang of things and i dont know how to link and how to proceed with creating store procedure for this. or how to write a c# code so that it takes the data and pass it to the stored procedure. if anyone could show me the steps or any link.... it wld be great

Comment: You should start at the beginning. Learn c#, then ado.net with c#, then sql server queries, then sql server stored procedures, then look into the articles posted by @benjamin in the answer below. Now your question is the equivalent of asking how to write an essay about cars in English but you understand neither English or cars. Without understanding the building blocks I outlined you will not get very far.

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server has extensive support for XML but until Sql Server 2016 it had no interfaces for JSON types. To see a very good approach to dealing with JSON before 2016 please read the article in Simple Talk titled, [Consuming JSON strings in Sql Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/). For 2016 see the Simple Talk article titled,[JSON support in Sql Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/json-support-in-sql-server-2016/).

Comment: is XML for only storing large data ? what if i need to store small amount of data like 10 columns and 120 rows..

Comment: The XML type, which is very different then JSON can be used for small amounts of data.